# Not able to handle the cookies page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I am launching below website, not able to handle the below cookies page. I want to click on "Allow Cookies" button on that frame. Please help me on this.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/home");
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Netherl ")).click();
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. What is the 'Allow cookies' button, and what does the rest of your page look like?

Comment: If you run above code, it webpage gets launched with the coockies page. Screenshot of this is shared on below path.    (http://imgur.com/jJ8Jb6Z) Because of that I am not able to proceed. Sorry for the confusion, please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: In your code you are trying to click `Netherl`. Where is that? If you are trying to click `Allow Cookies` click it by cssSelector . `.button.allow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='button allow']/span[text()='Allow cookies']")).click();
```

it will click on `Allow cookies` button.

Comment: Yes, its working. Thanks. Also I tried with below command.  {driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.button.allow > span")).click();}

Answer (score 0):

If you click the 'Accept' button, two cookies are set: `ns-cookie-toestemming` with value `ja`, and `ns-cookie-toestemming-datum` with a URL-encoded value of the time, like this `27-1-2015%2012%3A3` (encoded from `27-1-2015 12:3`).

According to the [Selenium documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#cookies) you should be able to set cookies for the user. If you set these cookies, the user should not get the cookie consent popup.